# JsonTemplateLayout - eventTemplate - missing values

Tags: log4j2

I've implemented log4j2:2.1.2.RELEASE with JsonTemplateLayout.eventTemplate and found some missing values such as line_number. Is there anything that I need to set up separately on the application code?

currently,
timestamp, level, host-name, mdc, thread-name, logger-name, exception, message, version look ok.
class, method, line_number, and file are missing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Julia, you need to have `locationInfoEnabled` set to `true`. (Note that location info access is disabled by default for performance reasons.)